# Non-existence of natural numbers such that $\sqrt{n} +\sqrt{n+1} <\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{y} <\sqrt{4n+2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Show that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there does not exist natural numbers $x,y$ such that $$\sqrt{n} +\sqrt{n+1} <\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{y} <\sqrt{4n+2}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume on the contrary that there is such $x, y$. Show $x+y \geq 2n+1$. Write $x+y=2n+1+k, k \geq 0$ and show $(2n+1-k)^2-1<4xy<(2n+1-k)^2$.

**Hint 2:** To show the last part, square the original inequality, shift some terms, and square again. Proving the lower bound will require slightly more work than the upper bound.

---

**Edit:** Since you appear to have so much difficulty with the lower bound, I guess it would be best to explain in more detail.

As mentioned in the second hint, square both sides and subtract $x+y$ to get

$$2n+1+2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-(x+y)<2\sqrt{xy}<4n+2-(x+y)$$

Since $x+y=2n+1+k$,

$$2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-k<2\sqrt{xy}<2n+1-k$$

The upper bound trivially implies $k<2n+1$, so $k \leq 2n$, so $k<2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}$.

Thus the lower bound is positive, and we may square again.

$$(2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-k)^2<4xy<(2n+1-k)^2$$

For the lower bound,

\begin{align}
& (2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-k)^2-((2n+1-k)^2-1)\\
& =(4n(n+1)+k^2-4k\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1})-(4n^2+4n+1+k^2-2k(2n+1)-1)\\
&=2k(2n+1-2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}) \\
&\geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: But how to show that $(2n+1-k)^2 -1 <4xy<(2n+1-k)^2 $?

Comment: @FisiaiLusia Have you shown $x+y \geq 2n+1$? What have you tried in relation to my hint?

Comment: Yes, if $x+y < 2n+1$ then $$\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{y} <\sqrt{2n+1 +2\sqrt{xy}} \leq \sqrt{n} +\sqrt{n+1} .$$

Comment: Oh I see, if $x+y =2n+1+k $ and $\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{y} <\sqrt{4n+2}$ then $$2\sqrt{xy} <4n+2 -(x+y) =2n+1-k$$ hence $$4xy< (2n+1-k)^2$$

Comment: But, how to show that $4xy>(2n+1-k)^2 -1$?

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see how to show that $4xy>(2n+1-k)^2 -1 .$

Comment: @FisiaiLusia When you do the same thing for the lower bound, you get a lower bound for $4xy$. Show that this lower bound is greater than $(2n+1-k)^2-1$ (you will need to expand and cancel terms)

Comment: I get a inequality $(2k-1)^2 <8kn$ but I don't know if it is true?